Zoe jacking points
I am looking for the jacking points of a Renault Zoe Ze40 (year 2017).

Background information:

I want to jack the car up to remove a wheel, so that I can remove wheel arch trim, so that I can fix water drain.

There are no triangle markings on the sills.


